# How can I add broad image recognition to a mobile app?

Tags: android, image-processing, mobile, neural-network, image-recognition

I'm working on an Android app (though eventually I'll want to do the same thing on iOS) and I'm looking to build an image recognition feature into it. The user would snap a picture, then this component of the app would need to figure out what that image is, whether it's a bowling ball, a salad, a book, you name it. It would also be helpful if it could figure out roughly how big the object in question is, though I imagine the camera focus values could help with that. The objects in question would not be moving.

I've heard of neural networks being used, but I'm not sure how this could be implemented, especially since I want to be able to recognize a very wide range of objects. I highly doubt this sort of processing could happen natively on a phone either. What are some solutions to this problem?

Comment: While this question is interesting, it's actually **off-topic for StackOverflow**.  I wish you the best of luck with your project, but before asking next time, it might be a good idea to read the *How To Ask* article.

Comment: where would be a good place for me to ask this kind of question? I feel like reddit could work, but the neural network subreddit is small so that isn't exactly ideal.

Comment: @altocumulus this question is a _very_ poor fit for Programmers - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6490#6490 Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you look at OpenCV. They have an awesome open source library for image processing and object detection. They also have great Android sample apps ready for testing some of their APIs.

http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html

Comment: this looks like a step in the right direction, thanks!